# ConnectionWithRequest is Deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios9, nsurlsession

I want to download some items from my host, 
but now I get a warning: 
**'connectionWithRequest:delegate:'is deprecated in iOS9.0 - Use NSURLSession'**

I've searched everywhere, but unfortunately I couldn't find any solution.

Can you help me?

My code looks like this:

```
- (void)downloadItems
{
    // Download the json file
    NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myhost.com/test.php"];

    // Create the request
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];

    // Create the NSURLConnection
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // Initialize the data object
    _downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the newly downloaded data
    [_downloadedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Create an array to store the locations
    NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Parse the JSON that came in
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    // Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

        // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
        Location *newLocation = [[Location alloc] init];
        newLocation.idS = jsonElement[@"idStatistic"];
        newLocation.temp = jsonElement[@"temp"];
        newLocation.hum = jsonElement[@"hum"];
        newLocation.date_time = jsonElement[@"date_time"];

        // Add this question to the locations array
        [_locations addObject:newLocation];
    }

    // Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
    if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_locations];
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says that you should use `NSURLSession`. Are you saying that you really couldn't find anything that described how to use `NSURLSession`?!? That's surprising as it's a well covered topic.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to replace it with NSURLSession. Can you help me to replace my code with NSURLSession? I'm new in this area, I would be really thankful to you.

Answer (score 5):

Replacing `NSURLConnection` line with:

```
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:jsonFileUrl
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                // handle response

            }] resume];
```